# Two Jumbotrons in One Row in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Looking to get two Jumbotrons in one row in Bootstrap, which I've done successfully in the code below, but they are directly side by side, so they touch. I would like to get some separation between them. I've tried changing the col-sm-6 to col-sm-5, but it creates a space on the wrong side. Any solutions for me?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="well-lg">
    <div class="one">
    <div class="jumbotron col-sm-6 text-center">
      <div class="text-center">
        <p>Caption</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm ban-default">Link & Such</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    <div class="jumbotron col-sm-6 text-center">
        <p>Caption</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm ban-default">Link & Such</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.one .jumbotron
{ background-image:url('Img');
color:white;
padding-top: 0;
min-height:200px;
min-width:45%;
border-radius:0;
}

.two .jumbotron
{ background-image:url('Img');
color:white;
padding-top: 0;
min-height:200px;
min-width:45%;
border-radius:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried changing the col-sm-6 to col-sm-5, but it creates a space on the wrong side.

I hope you want to use offset like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
```

and for the next div:

```
<div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
```

Now, the space is between col-sm-6 and col-sm-5 and the space is equal to 1 column width.